# dpkg-source: Errore: unrepresentable changes to source

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

I'm trying to build Kernel Source of xen gvt linux following this guide (it should be done on ubuntu 18) :

https://github.com/intel/gvt-linux/wiki/GVTg_Setup_Guide#332-build-qemu--xen-for-xengt

The commands that I should issue are the following :

```
git clone https://github.com/intel/gvt-linux.git

cd gvt-linux

git checkout gvt-stable-4.17

echo ""|make oldconfig


make -j8 && make modules_install && make install
```

When I try to generate the kernel Debian package directly and install it with below commands, I get an error that I'm not able to fix. Can some one help me ?

root@zio-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/etc/xen/gvt-linux# cat .config | grep CONFIG_DRM_I915_GVT

```
CONFIG_DRM_I915_GVT=y
CONFIG_DRM_I915_GVT_KVMGT=m
CONFIG_DRM_I915_GVT_XENGT=y
```

root@zio-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/etc/xen/gvt-linux#  cat .config | grep CONFIG_DRM_I915_GVT_KVMGT

```
CONFIG_DRM_I915_GVT_KVMGT=m
```

root@zio-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/etc/xen/gvt-linux#  cat .config | grep CONFIG_DRM_I915_GVT_XENGT

```
CONFIG_DRM_I915_GVT_XENGT=y

root@zio-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/etc/xen/gvt-linux# make -j8 deb-pkg
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
make clean
  CLEAN   .
  CLEAN   arch/x86/lib
  CLEAN   certs
  CLEAN   arch/x86/entry/vdso
  CLEAN   arch/x86/kernel/cpu
  CLEAN   arch/x86/purgatory
  CLEAN   arch/x86/kernel
  CLEAN   arch/x86/realmode/rm
  CLEAN   kernel/debug/kdb
  CLEAN   lib/raid6
  CLEAN   security/apparmor
  CLEAN   lib
  CLEAN   security/selinux
  CLEAN   usr
  CLEAN   security/tomoyo
  CLEAN   samples/hidraw
  CLEAN   arch/x86/boot/compressed
  CLEAN   arch/x86/boot
  CLEAN   arch/x86/tools
  CLEAN   drivers/firmware/efi/libstub
  CLEAN   net/wireless
  CLEAN   drivers/gpu/drm/radeon
  CLEAN   drivers/net/wan
  CLEAN   drivers/scsi/aic7xxx
  CLEAN   drivers/tty/vt
  CLEAN   drivers/scsi
  CLEAN   .tmp_versions
/bin/bash ./scripts/package/mkdebian
  TAR     linux-4.17.0+.tar.gz
origversion=$(dpkg-parsechangelog -SVersion |sed 's/-[^-]*$//');\
    mv linux-4.17.0+.tar.gz ../linux-4.17.0+_${origversion}.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-buildpackage -r"fakeroot -u" -a$(cat debian/arch) -i.git -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: Avviso: Usare un gain-root-command con privilegi di amministrazione
dpkg-buildpackage: Informazioni: Pacchetto sorgente linux-4.17.0+
dpkg-buildpackage: Informazioni: Versione sorgente 4.17.0+-3
dpkg-buildpackage: Informazioni: Distribuzione sorgente bionic
dpkg-buildpackage: Informazioni: Sorgente modificata da Anonymous 

<root@zio-Z390-AORUS-PRO>

dpkg-buildpackage: Informazioni: Architettura host amd64
 dpkg-source -i.git --before-build gvt-linux
 fakeroot -u debian/rules clean
rm -rf debian/*tmp debian/files
make clean
 dpkg-source -i.git -b gvt-linux
dpkg-source: Avviso: no source format specified in debian/source/format, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: Informazioni: using source format '1.0'
dpkg-source: Avviso: source directory 'gvt-linux' is not <sourcepackage>-<upstreamversion> 'linux-4.17.0+-4.17.0+'
dpkg-source: Avviso: .orig directory name gvt-linux.orig is not <package>-<upstreamversion> (wanted linux-4.17.0+-4.17.0+.orig)
dpkg-source: Informazioni: building linux-4.17.0+ using existing linux-4.17.0+_4.17.0+.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: Informazioni: building linux-4.17.0+ in linux-4.17.0+_4.17.0+-3.diff.gz
dpkg-source: Errore: cannot represent change to vmlinux-gdb.py:
dpkg-source: Errore:   new version is symlink to /etc/xen/gvt-linux/scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py
dpkg-source: Errore:   old version is nonexistent
dpkg-source: Avviso: ignoring deletion of file .scmversion, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: Avviso: the diff modifies the following upstream files: 
 .clang-format
 .cocciconfig
 .config.old
 .get_maintainer.ignore
 .mailmap
 .version
 CREDITS
 LICENSES/exceptions/Linux-syscall-note
 LICENSES/other/GPL-1.0
 LICENSES/other/MPL-1.1
 LICENSES/preferred/BSD-2-Clause
 LICENSES/preferred/BSD-3-Clause
 LICENSES/preferred/BSD-3-Clause-Clear
 LICENSES/preferred/GPL-2.0
 LICENSES/preferred/LGPL-2.0
 LICENSES/preferred/LGPL-2.1
 LICENSES/preferred/MIT
 MAINTAINERS
 Module.symvers
 README
dpkg-source: Informazioni: use the '3.0 (quilt)' format to have separate and documented changes to upstream files, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: Errore: unrepresentable changes to source
dpkg-buildpackage: Errore: dpkg-source -i.git -b gvt-linux subprocess returned exit status 1
scripts/package/Makefile:71: recipe for target 'deb-pkg' failed
make[1]: *** [deb-pkg] Error 1
Makefile:1408: recipe for target 'deb-pkg' failed
```

NB :

**I'm reading how to do that from here :

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234507/kernel-compilation-error-recipe-for-target-deb-pkg-failed

it seems that this is the right command to give :

```
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-custom kernel_image kernel_headers
```

so,in my case I know,from the guide,that the kernel_image should be called : linux-image-4.17.0+_4.17.0+-2_amd64.deb,but I don't know the name of the headers

a command like this :

```
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-custom linux-image-4.17.0+_4.17.0+-2_amd64.deb linux-headers-4.17.0+_4.17.0+-2_amd64.deb
```

gives the error : **use --targets to display help on valid targets.**

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer to your questions just on documentation, i.e. here : https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dpkg-dev/dpkg-source.1.en.html

Have a nice day!

Comment: Could you improve your answer adding the parts of the documentation that refer directly to the OP question? It's good to add the essential details inside the answer, so that everyone can read/implement the solution without going out the AskUbuntu site. Thanks :-)

Comment: I have added more details on the question. refresh page.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.